# White lines in email messages on iPhone with split images

Tags: html, html-email

We found a snippet of code for our email messages that will resize the email for mobile devices but maintains the size of the text.

We use split images for our email messages with text above the image.  The problem is we are getting a white line in the image at the tr command. The image displays with no white lines if the following code is removed from the header. When I add the code back I cannot get rid of the white line when viewing the email on the iPhone or a Droid.  It displays perfectly on the desktop/laptop in all email clients.

Here is the code that we placed in the head section.

```
<style type="text/css"> @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
  {/*CSS styles here will be applied on supporting mobile devices*/
  table, div {width:100% !important; max-width: 600px !important; position:relative !important; height:auto !important; overflow:hidden !important; top:0px !important;}
  img {max-width:100%; height: auto !important;}}
</style>
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the white line?

Answer (score 0):

try `display:block;` in your image tag.

Comment: We have display:block in the image tag.  There are no problems with a white line when viewed on a laptop or PC in any email client.  It is only on the iPhone or the Droid when the above code is added.

Comment: Can you post the effected area of your html also?

Answer (score 0):

The position:relative seems odd to me. I also don't think you need to specify height:auto !important;

If you are trying to make your images responsive, i.e. always 100% width of it's container element you can just specify width="100% and leave out the height specification. It will scale  in the proper ratio.

If you just need some code to stop your text above the images from resizing on mobile devices for instance iPhones etc. these are what I've been using.

```
div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
     #outlook a {padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in
browser" menu link. */
     html{width: 100%; }
     body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
     /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing
default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
     .ExternalClass {width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at
full width */
     .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /*   

Hotmail to display normal line spacing. */
     .backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;
line-height: 100% !important;}
     img {outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
```